# Docker containers not stopping

Tags: docker, containers

I do have `docker` daemon running in my host and, there are a few docker images that I intend on using. But while checking on the currently running containers I could see 2 containers running related to 2 images out of the few, within the time of docker daemon being up.

```
[~]$ docker container ls
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                               NAMES
1faea3942353        backend_djapp   "python manage.py ru…"   13 days ago         Up 1 second         0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp              backend_djapp_1
c400b19b6110        mysql               "docker-entrypoint.s…"   13 days ago         Up 1 second         33060/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3308->3306/tcp   backend_mysql_1
```

Is there any reason which this could have occurred? How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove that container completely try this command :

```
docker system prune
```

This command will remove everything from docker images , container

Or

```
docker container stop <container-id>
```

This command will stop your container

Then

```
docker container rm <container-id>
```

This command will remove that container for your

Before removing any container you should need to stop that container first.